# Symfony 7 problem with verify user email function

Tags: php, symfony

Good morning.
I'm training on Symfony 7 (without too many problems so far) but now I have a problem.
For infocrmation :
**PHP : 8.2.13**, **Composer 2.7.1**, Windows 11 64 (we never know ^^)

When the user wants to register, he receives an email address confirmation email, when he clicks on it, he is redirected to the '/login' page but the user's email address does not have not been verified.
So he can't connect.
The user is in the DB.
I don't have any error messages.

The validation links received by the user are in the form:
**http://localhost:8000/verify/email?expires=1711156044&signature=nn5%2BIfAw8bzly1yrXpSDDC92QZY61n0n8gGojDFgXJQ%3D&token=Sgpw23MGVEqVclZxG%2FV2OX%2FOrWq6jo20m95eRtu%2BeAU%3D**

I give you the code of my **RegistrationController**
I suppose the problem comes from the **verifyUserEmail **method

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\RegistrationFormType;
use App\Security\AppAuthenticator;
use App\Security\EmailVerifier;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Security;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Address;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Attribute\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\UserAuthenticatorInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface;
use SymfonyCasts\Bundle\VerifyEmail\Exception\VerifyEmailExceptionInterface;

class RegistrationController extends AbstractController
{
    private EmailVerifier $emailVerifier;

    public function __construct(EmailVerifier $emailVerifier, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->emailVerifier = $emailVerifier;
        $this->logger =$logger;
    }

    #[Route('/register', name: 'app_register')]
    public function register(Request $request, UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPasswordHasher, UserAuthenticatorInterface $userAuthenticator, AppAuthenticator $authenticator, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $user->setPassword(
                $userPasswordHasher->hashPassword(
                    $user,
                    $form->get('plainPassword')->getData()
                )
            );

            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();

            $this->emailVerifier->sendEmailConfirmation('app_verify_email', $user,
                (new TemplatedEmail())
                    ->from(new Address('flow@flow.fr', 'Flow'))
                    ->to($user->getEmail())
                    ->subject('Confirmez votre e-mail')
                    ->htmlTemplate('registration/confirmation_email.html.twig')
            );;
            return $this->redirectToRoute('home.index');
        }

        return $this->render('registration/register.html.twig',[
            'registrationForm' => $form->createView()
        ]);

    }

    #[Route('/verify/email', name: 'app_verify_email')]
    public function verifyUserEmail(Request $request, TranslatorInterface $translator, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');

        $user = $this->getUser();
        $token = $request->get('token');

        if ($user && $this->isCsrfTokenValid('verify_email', $token)) {
            try {
                $this->emailVerifier->handleEmailConfirmation($request, $user);
                return $this->redirectToRoute('app_login');
            } catch (VerifyEmailExceptionInterface $exception) {
                $this->addFlash('verify_email_error', $translator->trans($exception->getReason(), [], 'VerifyEmailBundle'));
            }
        } else {
            $this->addFlash('verify_email_error', 'Les données de vérification d\'e-mail ne sont pas valides.');
        }
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_login');
    }

}
```

I dont know it can healp but my composer.json :

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.2",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.12",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.3",
        "doctrine/orm": "^3.1",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.3",
        "phpstan/phpdoc-parser": "^1.26",
        "symfony/asset": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/asset-mapper": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/console": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/doctrine-messenger": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2",
        "symfony/form": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/intl": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/mime": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/notifier": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/process": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/stimulus-bundle": "^2.16",
        "symfony/string": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/translation": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/validator": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "7.0.*",
        "symfonycasts/verify-email-bundle": "^1.17",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "vich/uploader-bundle": "^2.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "php-http/discovery": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php81": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php82": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd",
            "importmap:install": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "7.0.*"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^7.0",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "7.0.*"
    }
}
```

I use MailDev for sending emails

---

**EDIT :**
I try :

```
<?php
public function verifyUserEmail(Request $request, TranslatorInterface $translator, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');
    try {
        $this->emailVerifier->handleEmailConfirmation($request, $this->getUser());
    }catch (VerifyEmailExceptionInterface $exception){
        $this->addFlash('verify_email_error', $translator->trans($exception->getReason(), [], 'VerifyEmailBundle'));
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_register');
    }
    $this->addFlash('success', 'Your email has been verified.');
    return $this->redirectToRoute('app_register');
}
```

---

An unregistered user cannot browse all pages of the site.
To do this, you must register.
He registers with a form and when the form is submitted, he receives an email to confirm his email address with a link that validates his email address with an "isVerifey = true" field in the database and then is redirected to the login page which displays a flash message stating that their email address is verified. He can therefore connect and access all the pages of the site.

I hope I was clearer in my information.

---

**Edit**

I found the problem. It did not come from the **verifyUserEmail** function but from the **register** function.

I replaced `return $this->redirectToRoute('home.index');`
by  `return $userAuthenticator->authenticateUser($user, $authenticator, $request);`
in **register** function.

Thank for your help.

Comment: Please don't add solutions in the question. If you think your solution can help other people in the future then please post the answer, otherwise you can also delete the question